# std::iterator segmentation fault when using it as a class variable

Tags: c++, iterator

Consider the following snippet

```
class ItrTest {
private:
    std::map<int, long> testMap;
    std::map<int, long>::iterator itr;

public:
    ItrTest(std::map<int, long> testMap): testMap(testMap) {
        itr = testMap.begin();
    }

    void printNext() {
        // itr = testMap.begin();
        for (; itr != testMap.end(); itr++) {
            cout<<"Key: "<<itr->first<<" Value:"<<itr->second<<endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, long> m{
        { 0, 100l },
        { 1, 200l },
        { 2, 300l },
        { 3, 400l },
        { 4, 500l },
    };

    ItrTest t(std::move(m));
    t.printNext();
}
```

This throws a segmentation fault when trying to access the values inside the iterator. It is obvious this happens because the iterator becomes invalid (for me after a couple of iterations. Maybe it behaves differently on different systems). If I uncomment the first line of the function `printNext()` it works fine. I would like to get an explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: `testMap(testMap)`?! Why would anyone do that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor, for `itr = testMap.begin();`, `testMap` refer to the function parameter, not the data member. It'll be destryoed when get out of the constructor, left `itr` dangled. Any dereference on it later leads to UB.

You could change it to

```
itr = this->testMap.begin();
```